# how can i run an other java program/class from an action?

Tags: java

Hi I'd like to knew how I can run / start another class(from the same package) in my program. I want it to run independent but at the same time I'd like it to be packed in my jar.

Comment: Start by reading this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: As in multiple `main()` entry points in one jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Possible solution:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        SomeClass.main(new String[]{});
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: you're missing a `);`

Comment: Thanks, my eye for detail isn't what it used to be!

Comment: Beauty of IDE's, is it doesn't have to be :)